# If monarchs have "subjects", what do caliphs have?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is the usage in English (be it an imported Arabic transliterated word) for 'subject' as in 'the subjects of a monarch' but of a caliph?  In other words, what is a 'subject' of a caliphate called?

My context is Islamic (particularly Abbasid Caliphate) culture.  I would prefer to import the Arabic transliterated word into English rather than use an English word such as 'subject' or 'citizen'.

Comment: So you are thinking that a caliph is not a type of monarch?

Comment: Subjects seems to be the right word for caliphs too ... E.g. https://www.routledge.com/Caliphs-and-their-Non-Muslim-Subjects-A-Critical-Study-of-the-Covenant/Tritton/p/book/9780415611817

Comment: @GEdgar : A caliph was a type of theocracy, whereas of monarchies of modern times operate in a system other than a theocracy (usually).  This word I am looking for is to be used in a historical context anyway.

Comment: Perhaps 'adherent'. Theocracies are complex; if God is seen as the ultimate Lord, those humans appointed to be in leadership won't have their own 'subjects'. I suppose with false religions (Caesar is (a) G/god), the situation becomes even more difficult (and to be avoided).

Comment: You'd have to pick a religion. In the one I was raised as, it's called a *flock* or a *parish*. The hypernym would be *follower*.

Comment: @Mazura : I think the words _flock_, _follower_, and to some extent _parish_ (when used anthropologically not geographically/demographically) are <members> of a subset (or micro) authority, such as a church/temple.  I am looking for a word in the macro-authority context of a caliphate/empire/country.

Comment: I couldn't tell ya; religion isn't something I still *ascribe to*. ... "transitive verb. : to refer to a supposed cause, source, or author : to say or think that (something) is caused by, comes from, or is associated with a particular person or thing"

Comment: @GrandTorini : Thanks for the link, but your conclusion of "subjects seems to be the right word for caliph[ate]s too" from the context of the book 'Caliphs and their Non-Muslim Subjects' (even just the title) is completely wrong.  The 'Covenant of Umar' (aka. Pact of Umar) was a treaty of differentiation between two parties: Muslims and non-Muslims.  The word '_subject_' cannot be used on its own in this context.  In the title of the book it uses the  '**_Non-Muslim_**' qualifier.  This is the reason for my question, I would like a self-qualifying single word, to be less-technical and flowing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : '_[An] adherent_' seems more impersonal and more constrictive than the word  '_subject_'.  'Adherent' will also require a qualifier to answer _ _adhere to what/who?_.  If I have to keep putting qualifiers with 'adherent' in my text, the flow of the text will be disrupted.  This also becomes a problem when the context includes both 'subjects of a monarch' and a those of a caliphate.

Comment: 'Subject' also requires a referent, and defaults in English to the sense of a citizen in say the UK under a constitutional monarchy (it is rarely used apart from in official usages) or historically subjection to an unelected monarch. It in no way connotes religious followers: the notion of control by a prelate is very foreign. // I'm not sure why you write "The word 'subject' cannot be used on its own in this context" above after, if I'm reading things in the right order, accepting the term as an answer. If you're seeking a word to address a typical English audience (and to do otherwise ...

Comment: would be to be asking an off-topic question on ELU) then if 'subject' is the least worst term to use, an explanation of the non-standard way in which you're pressing it into service in writing is almost mandatory.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : I have accepted the word '_subject_' because of the absence of an answer. رَعِيَّة is the answer in Arabic, but this does not appear in the English language. The imported word (from Arabic) _ummah_ (_community_) does not read well in English and also in Arabic, particularly when used for a singular person. '_Subject_' in English is specifically associated with a '_person under the rule of a monarchy_'. In the Arabic language a caliphate is different to a monarchy: the word for caliph is خِلَافَة‎, but Arabic also has a word for king: _malik_ ملك.

Comment: If 'subject' _is_ the least worst term to use, an explanation of the non-standard way in which you're pressing it into service in writing, _when you use it_, is almost mandatory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Subjects Temporal and Spiritual

English does not provide a word for those subject to spiritual authority
that is any way distinct from the word used for those subject to temporal
authority (meaning secular or civil authority). We have always used *subject*
for both of those.

Its main etymon from classical Latin per the OED is:

> classical Latin *subiectus* (masculine) person ruled by a monarch or
> sovereign state, subordinate, dependant, in post-classical Latin also
> person under the spiritual guidance of a priest or pastor (6th cent.),
> vassal (10th cent.)

(There is also a post-classical Latin etymon *subiectum* (neuter) used for
a grammatical, musical, or legal subject.)

They show these relevant senses:

> I. Someone or something under a person’s rule or control.
>
> 1. a. A person who is under the control of another or who owes obedience
>    to another.  Also in extended use of an animal, etc.  Frequently with
>    possessive or *of*-phrase. Also with †*to*.
> 2. a. A person bound to another by an obligation of allegiance, service,
>    or tribute; spec. a feudal tenant or vassal; (hence) †a dependant, a
>    subordinate, a person of inferior status. Now *historical.* 
>     b. A
>    person who owes allegiance or obedience to a spiritual superior. Now
>    chiefly *historical*. 
>     †c. A person under the spiritual guidance of a
>    priest or pastor; any of a parish priest’s parishioners. *Obsolete.*
> 3. A person owing allegiance to and under the protection of a monarch or
>    government; a person (other than the monarch) living under a monarchy.

So our English word came to us **already possessed** of senses both
temporal and spiritual when we initially grafted it into our language from
Middle French by way of Anglo-Norman French.  Indeed, I know of no other
word used for the distinction you seek in any of the related modern Romance
languages, including French (*sujet*), Italian¹ (*soggetto*), Spanish
(*sujeto*), or Portuguese (*sujeito*).

If by chance you happen know of one commonly used now or in the past in any of those
Romance languages, I would quite be interested in learning it — preferably
without having to first read through reams and reams of Old Castilian
written a millennium ago about the Caliphate of Córdoba that existed there
under the Umayyad dynasty during 929–1031. :)

---

#### Footnotes

1. As pointed out in comments, for people who are subjects of a ruler, Italian uses a slightly different word, *suddito*. I mentioned Italian *soggetto* because it is
   equally descended from the same Latin etymon *subiectus/subiectum <
   subicio/subicere/subieci/subiectum < sub + iaceo/iacere* that the others
   use, including English via French. 
   But Italian uses *soggetto* **only**
   for the “topic or theme” senses of *subject* — like those from the
   grammatical, legal, and musical domains.  For **people** like the ones the asker wanted to know about, ones who (are subject / have submitted) to
   some authority, Italians instead use *suddito* < Latin *subditus <
   subdo/subdere/subdidi/subditum < sub + do/dare*.

Comment: Thank you tchrist.  I will concede and stick with 'subject'.

Comment: Note, my differentiation was not merely a temporal (secular or civil) vs. spiritual authority, but with more emphasis on an Arabic vs. native language paradigm.  For instance king in English Monarchy vs. tsar in Slavic Monarchy vs. caliph in Islamic Caliphate.

Comment: @MohammedibnDawud What was the specific, distinctive term for this in Arabic which you had been thinking of simply transliterating?

Comment: Soggetto is not used in Italian with the same meaning, 'suddito' is the correct translation, e.g. 'suddito di Sua Maestà'

Comment: @GrandTorini Good point! Added footnote with the distinction.

Comment: @tchrist: I was thinking of '_ummah_' (أمة) which is translated as 'community'.